# flutter/dart: how to control the column size?

Tags: flutter, dart

I need to display a set of options on a pop-up.
The issue that I am having is that the column is taking up all the space.
is there a way around this or another widget I should be using?

I tried using list view but it nothing ends up showing up

[image: dialog pop up]

```
  _displayJobTypeAlert(BuildContext context) {
    return showDialog(
      builder: (context) {
        return AlertDialog(
          title: Text('What type of job is this?'),
          content: Column(
            //shrinkWrap: true,

            // ignore: prefer_const_literals_to_create_immutables
            children: [
              TextButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  _updateJobField(_jobType, jobTypeColumn, 'Handyman');
                },
                child: const Text('Handyman'),
              ),
              TextButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  _updateJobField(_jobType, jobTypeColumn, 'Landscaping');
                },
                child: const Text('Landscaping'),
              ),
              TextButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  _updateJobField(_jobType, jobTypeColumn, 'Plumming');
                },
                child: const Text('Plumming'),
              ),
              TextButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  _updateJobField(_jobType, jobTypeColumn, 'Remodeling');
                },
                child: const Text('Remodeling'),
              ),
              TextButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  _updateJobField(_jobType, jobTypeColumn, 'Roofing');
                },
                child: const Text('Roofing'),
              ),
              TextButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  _updateJobField(_jobType, jobTypeColumn, 'Electrical');
                },
                child: const Text('Electrical'),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        );
      },
      context: context,
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

Instruct the `Column` widget to take the minimum size it requires:

```
Column(
   mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
   children: [...]
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I took out column

I used actions instead of children and it worked!

```
  Future _displayJobTypeAlert(BuildContext context) {
    return showDialog(
      builder: (context) {
        return AlertDialog(
          elevation: 24.0,
          title: Text('What type of job is this?'),
          actions:
              //Column(
              //shrinkWrap: true,

              // ignore: prefer_const_literals_to_create_immutables
              //children:
              [
            TextButton(
              onPressed: () {
                _updateJobField(_jobType, jobTypeColumn, 'Handyman');
                Navigator.pop(context);
              },
              child: const Text('Handyman'),
            ),
            TextButton(
              onPressed: () {
                _updateJobField(_jobType, jobTypeColumn, 'Landscaping');
                Navigator.pop(context);
              },
              child: const Text('Landscaping'),
            ),
            TextButton(
              onPressed: () {
                _updateJobField(_jobType, jobTypeColumn, 'Plumming');
                Navigator.pop(context);
              },
              child: const Text('Plumming'),
            ),
            TextButton(
              onPressed: () {
                _updateJobField(_jobType, jobTypeColumn, 'Remodeling');
                Navigator.pop(context);
              },
              child: const Text('Remodeling'),
            ),
            TextButton(
              onPressed: () {
                _updateJobField(_jobType, jobTypeColumn, 'Roofing');
                Navigator.pop(context);
              },
              child: const Text('Roofing'),
            ),
            TextButton(
              onPressed: () {
                _updateJobField(_jobType, jobTypeColumn, 'Electrical');
                Navigator.pop(context);
              },
              child: const Text('Electrical'),
            ),
          ],
          //),
        );
      },
      context: context,
    );
  }
```

Comment: Wouldn't that display the buttons side by side? If you want to have them below each other, try setting mainAxisSize to MainAxisSize.min, see @Peter Koltai answer